# How to get the variable from a text box of the previous page to the next page?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a search box that leads to another page to execute the search. E.g. search in Inquirypage --> get result in Listpage. How do I get the value from Inquiry page to list page since they're not in the same class. Can i get some insights? Thank you

Search button from first page:

```
public async void FromBPSearchTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var BPSearch = Customer.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BPSearch))
        {
            BPSearch = string.Empty;
        }
        BPSearch = BPSearch.ToUpperInvariant();
    }
```

Comment: Please follow the site's guidelines: avoid putting tags in your question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the string as a parameter to the next page's constructor.
Sample code as below:

In your `InquiryPage.xaml.cs`

```
    private async void FromBPSearchTap(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //...
        //your code with BPSearch     
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListPage(BPSearch));
    }
```

In your next `ListPage.xaml.cs`

```
    string _searchText
    public ListPage(string searchText)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _searchText = searchText;  //have your text in ListPage now
    }
```